# Big Query Pagination in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, pagination, google-bigquery

I am trying to page through BigQuery data with vb.net. I keep getting the same first page of data with my code. The way I understand, I need to set the pagetoken of the response to look at the next page.

With the following code, I only get the first page of data while never exiting my loop.

For the login I was setting the Oauthtoken of my queryrequest and that was getting the first page fine, but no attempt is made to page through the results that way.

I appreciate any lead in the right direction.

```
    Dim DT As New DataTable
    Dim ErrMessage As String = ""
    Try
        Dim INIT As New BigqueryService.Initializer
        Dim scopes As IList(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
        scopes.Add(BigqueryService.Scope.Bigquery)
        Dim credential As UserCredential
        Using stream As New FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None, New FileDataStore("BQ.App")).Result
        End Using
        INIT.HttpClientInitializer = credential
        Dim service As New BigqueryService(INIT)
        Dim j As JobsResource = service.Jobs
        Dim req As New QueryRequest
        req.Query = tQuery.Text
        Dim QRequest As JobsResource.QueryRequest = j.Query(req, projectId)
        QRequest.OauthToken = MyAccessToken
        Dim JOBID As String = QRequest.Execute.JobReference.JobId
        Dim DATA = QRequest.Execute
        Dim schema = DATA.Schema
        For Each col In schema.Fields
            DT.Columns.Add(col.Name)
        Next
        Dim page_Tok = ""
        Dim rr As GetQueryResultsResponse
        While True
            Try
                rr.PageToken = page_Tok
            Catch ex As Exception
                 'No Token Yet
            End Try

            rr = j.GetQueryResults(projectId, JOBID).Execute

            page_Tok = rr.PageToken
            If rr.JobComplete = True Then
                If page_Tok = "" Then
                    Exit While
                End If
            End If
            Dim resp2 = rr.Rows
            For Each row In resp2
                Dim DR As DataRow = DT.NewRow
                For f = 0 To row.F.Count - 1
                    Dim field = row.F
                    DR(f) = row.F(f).V
                Next
                DT.Rows.Add(DR)
            Next
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrMessage = ex.Message
    End Try
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a VB expert, but you're not setting the page token in the GetQueryResultsRequest, you're setting it in the response. See https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Bigquery_1_1v2_1_1JobsResource_1_1GetQueryResultsRequest.html

I think that this will work:

```
        req = j.GetQueryResults(projectId, JOBID)
        req.PageToken = page_tok
        rr = req.Execute
```